# AppEngine app stops updating Firebase without error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, servlets

I have an AppEngine app that manipulates a Firebase DB through AppEngine [cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron).

Everything works well, except that after 24 hours the app stops writing to Firebase. Without any discernible error.

You can find my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Shacharit/Shacharit)

The database object is initialized during each servlet initialization [here](https://github.com/Shacharit/Shacharit/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/org/shaharit/face2face/backend/servlets/ShaharitServlet.java#L32). The database call that seems to fail is [here](https://github.com/Shacharit/Shacharit/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/org/shaharit/face2face/backend/services/FirebaseMatchingLog.java#L32), which is called from [here](https://github.com/Shacharit/Shacharit/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/org/shaharit/face2face/backend/tasks/MatchingTask.java#L37) on the main servlet thread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an extremely old, deprecated version of the Firebase java client SDK:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.5.2'
```

You should be using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) instead, which fixes known issues when running the Firebase SDK in App Engine.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'
```

Some APIs have changed, so you will need to adapt to them.

Comment: Thanks. I did this. Everything works locally but when I deploy I seem to be getting Guava related errors related to Guava. Same as appear [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/50) I tried upgrading the Guava version, but I can't as I'm using Java7. My dependencies look now like this:

    `appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.56'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.56'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'`

Comment: That sounds like a different question that requires different details to diagnose.